# SH Script working in console but not in Cronjob

Tags: linux, cron, raspberry-pi, debian

I have a Raspberry PI with Debian. I am also running Domoticz. Domoticz sometimes stops and I have to restart the service. I use this script (domoticz_state_checker.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Checking if Domoticz is running.'
DomoticzState=`sudo service domoticz.sh status`

#echo $DomoticzState

if [[ $DomoticzState == *"active (running)"* ]] 
then
    echo 'Domoticz is running. Nothing to do.'
elif [[ $DomoticzState == *"domoticz is not running ... failed!"* ]] 
then
    echo 'Domoticz is not running. Restarting Domoticz...'
    sudo service domoticz.sh restart
    echo 'Domoticz restarted.'
elif [[ $DomoticzState == *"active (exited)"* ]] 
then
    echo 'Domoticz active (exited). Restarting Domoticz...'
    sudo service domoticz.sh restart
    echo 'Domoticz restarted.'          
elif [[ $DomoticzState == *"inactive (dead)"* ]] 
then
    echo 'Domoticz inactive (dead). Restarting Domoticz...'
    sudo service domoticz.sh restart
    echo 'Domoticz restarted.'                      
fi
```

When I run this script as the user Pi the script works. I run it like this

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/domoticz/scripts $ /home/pi/domoticz/scripts/domoticz_state_checker.sh
```

I have created the following with crontab - e to run this as a cronjob

```
*/5 * * * * pi /home/pi/domoticz/scripts/domoticz_state_checker.sh >> /home/pi/domoticz/scripts/domoticz_state_checker.log 2>&1
```

In my cron log I see the job being executed:

```
Jan 10 14:55:01 raspberrypi CRON[23498]: (pi) CMD (pi /home/pi/domoticz/scripts/domoticz_state_checker.sh >> /home/pi/domoticz/scripts/domoticz_state_checker.log 2>&1)
```

But the script doesn't restart my Domoticz service. The check is done but then I get errors on my if and elif statement. I see the following error in my domoticz_state_checker.log :

```
Checking if Domoticz is running.
/home/pi/domoticz/scripts/domoticz_state_checker.sh: 7: /home/pi/domoticz/scripts/domoticz_state_checker.sh: [[: not found
/home/pi/domoticz/scripts/domoticz_state_checker.sh: 10: /home/pi/domoticz/scripts/domoticz_state_checker.sh: [[: not found
/home/pi/domoticz/scripts/domoticz_state_checker.sh: 15: /home/pi/domoticz/scripts/domoticz_state_checker.sh: [[: not found
/home/pi/domoticz/scripts/domoticz_state_checker.sh: 20: /home/pi/domoticz/scripts/domoticz_state_checker.sh: [[: not found
```

When I execute with suo

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/domoticz/scripts $ sudo /home/pi/domoticz/scripts/domoticz_state_checker.sh
```

I get the same result as when I run the script via cron

Any ideas what is going wrong here?
Under which account is my cronjob executing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think to run shell script in cronjob as specific user you should `-u` option in crontab.

`crontab -u pi -e`

and before location file add command `bash` or `/bin/bash`

`#<timing>   <user> <command>`

`*/5 * * * *  bash /home/pi/domoticz/scripts/domoticz_state_checker.sh >> /home/pi/domoticz/scripts/domoticz_state_checker.log 2>&1`

you can find crontab from spool where is located file for all users

`cat /var/spool/cron/crontabs/<user>`

Comment: It looks like the job is under the pi account but when running its run with suo? And why can't I run my script with sudo

Comment: Using crontab -u pi -e gives the same jobs as crontab -e

Comment: when I run the command sudo bash /home/pi/domoticz/scripts/domoticz_state_checker.sh I don't get the errors. What does bash do? I am kind a new to Linux

Comment: @Danny, sorry i'm forgoteen to tell you, if you run script with sudo, it like you run script as root user. runing any application without `sudo` or with `sudo` is different, the `sudo` allows a user to run a program as another user (super-user / root).

if you want run with sudo, you can change user `pi` to `root` in `crontab` command (`crontab -u root -e`)

Comment: That's clear now. Thx. But what I don't get is that why the script fails when running with sudo but works when running as pi.

Comment: sure.. glad could help.. because `sudo` command can not use in `crontab` ...if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.